# React Native android build failed. SDK location not found

Tags: android, react-native

I have error when i start running android

```
What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.  
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

Comment: this was happening with me in the first ever hello world, even the env variable was set correctly, what I did is, open the android folder in android studio and hit the run button(green play icon) and it worked, make sure your metro is running while you are doing this, i think it was happening because i didnt opened the android studio after installation when I opened the android folder in andriod studio I noticed it updated few things and now even npm run android is working fine

Answer (score 1015):

- Go to the `android/` directory of your react-native project
- Create a file called `local.properties` with this line:

```
sdk.dir = /Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk
```

Where `USERNAME` is your macOS username

Comment: * What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> The SDK directory '/usr/local/android-sdk  ' does not exist. But actually my sdk is exist in this path

Comment: Did you guys fix this issue? I'm also facing this right now.

Comment: I was able to fix this by running from Android Studio.   Once you've done that it works from the command-line.

Comment: Yeah creating that local.properties did solve my issue. Strange but works.

Comment: If your on windows `sdk.dir = C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk`

Comment: This works! Not sure why this answer is not in the top of the answers!

Comment: also make sure you have the android SDK installed https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html, if that's not obvious :)

Comment: `C:\Users\kalam\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`   it work for me

Comment: Hi, I'm new. May I know create what kind of file and name it `local.properties` ? `txt` or other format ?

Comment: this has fixed issue for me and I am able to issue react-native run-android which will install app on both emulator and real device when one is connected.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there a way not to do this every time ?

Comment: Check if your local.properties file format is not .txt or .rtf. It is .properties.

Comment: is there any way the local properties folder gets added by default , when starting a new react project , like in android studio it gets added automatically .

Comment: A note to people who're editing this to exclude `/Users/USERNAME`: `sdk.dir` expects to be started with `/`, it doesn't take `~` as home directory

Comment: You should set the ANDROID_PATH instead of setting it in local.properties. Doing so will make it a permanent solution across all your projects, and will not cause problems to other dev in the team should the local.properties file get placed in a code revision tool.

Comment: Very late, very inexperience but: sdk.dir=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk

Comment: This solved the error. Inside the project folder, I created the new file local.properties and added the line you mentioned with my Mac username.

Comment: This error would specially appear if you have copied the project or downloaded the zip file . It woun't appear if it's a new project or it's been cloned from git

Comment: This only works per-project basis. Editing the system variables would be a better long-term solution if you're working with multiple projects.

Comment: for windows create file local.properties and paste 'sdk.dir = C:\\Users\\ [your User Name]\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk'

Comment: Future note: instead of this you will want to add enviromental variable to `eas.json` for the EAS builds

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 500):

**Solution:**

1. Go to your React-native Project
2. Inside android folder
3. Create a file named --> **local.properties**
4. Open the file
5. paste your Android SDK path which looks similar like below

   ```
   sdk.dir = C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk    --> for Windows

   sdk.dir = /Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk                  --> for  macOS     

   sdk.dir = /home/USERNAME/Android/Sdk                           --> for linux
   ```

Replace `USERNAME` with your OS username

6. ```
   cd android && ./gradlew clean
   ```
7. ```
   cd ..
   ```
8. ```
   npx react-native run-android
   ```

**That's it. It works!**

Comment: I moved my SDK to my external drive.

Works for me using macOS Sierra.

Comment: in linux `sdk.dir=/home/USERNAME/Android/Sdk`

Comment: sdk.dir = /home/USERNAME/Android/Sdk -> works for linux but Android Studio for  Linux needs to be present and working ( gradle running )

Comment: Showing error* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> The SDK directory '/Users/chandni sharma/Library/Android/sdk' does not exist.

Comment: @Chandni Make sure you have Android SDK installed

Comment: Worked like a charm made in my country.. Thanks! :D

Comment: @NaveenTP thank you very much i was going to drop learning native just because of this problem

Comment: thanks a lot. I didn't even know that the sdk is far away from location of android studio directory on windows 10.

Comment: I have installed Genymotion. Facing the same issue

Answer (score 136):

You can try adding ANDROID_PATH

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Comment: I already have `ANDROID_PATH` in environment (Ubuntu, .bashrc file). However, for some reasons I am still geting the issue. I fixed it by creating `local.properties` and putting the path as stated in other answers.

Comment: I have a mac and env var ANDROID_HOME did not help. `local.properties` did, however.

Comment: For me, I use direnv, so I added basically the same thing to `.env` and now `react-native run-android` at least launches the emulator.  i have `ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/; PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools` but on two lines.

Comment: THIS save me ! Thanks

Answer (score 82):

**Open `~/.bash_profile` and add:**

```
 export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk/
 export PATH=$PATH:~/android-sdks/platform-tools/
 export PATH=$PATH:~/android-sdks/tools/
```

**source ~/.bash_profile**

[image]

Comment: Works. Remember to restart Terminal, or type `source ~/.bash_profile` to make new export lines take in effect.

Comment: Can you please add if any body is unable to find the bash_profile then create one as  for the first timers they are unable to find that (So do I :p)

Answer (score 70):

I don't think it's recommended to update the `local.properties` file to get to add the missing environment vars.

### Update your environment variables:

> [How to open the AVD manager on OSX from iTerm2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65711364/how-to-open-the-avd-manager-on-osx-from-iterm2/65711365#65711365)

#### android-28 / android-30

sdk can be installed on /Library/Android/sdk or /usr/local/ to be sure check it by

```
which sdkmanager
```

#### Export ANDROID_HOME

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
```

or

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/usr/local/share/android-sdk"
```

Then add it to the $PATH

```
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/28.0.1:$PATH
```

#### android-23

```
export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/opt/ant
export MAVEN_HOME=/usr/local/opt/maven
export GRADLE_HOME=/usr/local/opt/gradle
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/share/android-sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/local/share/android-sdk
export ANDROID_NDK_HOME=/usr/local/share/android-ndk
export INTEL_HAXM_HOME=/usr/local/Caskroom/intel-haxm
```

I used `brew cask` to install **Android SDK** following [these instructions](https://gist.github.com/agrcrobles/165ac477a9ee51198f4a870c723cd441).

More info see https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update#sdk-manager

Comment: Thats the best answer, no need to change local.properties. Works perfect for me

Comment: why is that bad practice? genuinely curious as it seems like making a localized change is much safer than making a change to your system path

Comment: Because if this code will be checked into source control, the next person who tries to build with it will end up looking at this page.

Comment: Run Command `source ~/.bash_profile` for update/Refresh current terminal session.

Comment: Recent versions of iterm2 (I'm using 3.4), they use `zsh` so, write above lines to `$HOME/.zshrc`.

Comment: in ubuntu 20.04 the path is `export ANDROID_HOME=/home/(userName)/Android/Sdk`

Answer (score 38):

`echo "sdk.dir = /Users/$(whoami)/Library/Android/sdk" > android/local.properties`

Comment: This is the safest way as you are not changing any global system files. And for those that dont have that type of admin access to their machine.

Answer (score 29):

**Updated steps for React Native0.58 to get started on MAC/Unix**

- Open bash_profile in terminal

> nano  ~/.bash_profile

- Scroll to bottom and add this lines from https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started:

> export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
>
> export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
>
> export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
>
> export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
>
> export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

```
Control+S to save
Control+X to exit
Y to save changes
```

- Update changes in terminal

> `source ~/.bash_profile`

- Validate Path:

> `echo $PATH`

- Confirm if all okay:

> `adb devices`

Comment: Saved my life :)

Comment: Sometimes you need to close and re-open your terminal

Answer (score 28):

If you are on windows escape (add backlashes to) the backslashes and the colon in the `android/local.properties` file. If its not there then create it

```
sdk.dir = C\:\\Android\\sdk
```

Comment: For Windows, the Android SDK is under C:\Program Files \Android\android-sdk

Answer (score 28):

**For Windows Users**

One simple solution is to set the SDK path to the Enviroment Variables list.

1. Head over to the Enviromnent variables. (Your PC > Properties )
2. Create **New** System variables
3. Set the **Variable name** to **ANDROID_HOME**
4. Set the **Variable value** to your Android Sdk Location
5. Press OK (3 times for 3 dialog boxes)

**Note:**

Your Android Sdk is generally located in

***C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk***

Make sure to **close your current terminal** because your terminal holds all of your pre-existing Environment Variables.

Comment: That is it. No need to edit the local.properties, thank you.

Comment: Remember to reboot your machine

Comment: i missed that "close your current terminal" omg and i tried i almost gave up and i read again hahaha thanks! this worked!

Answer (score 16):

### Fixing SDK Path Errors on Linux Distributions

---

Your project is not finding the SDK set in the Project Settings via the path provided, so the project needs to be pointing in the right direction, and you have a couple options to accomplish this, but let's start by finding the correct SDK folder first.

---

## Finding your SDK

---

***From Package Manager***

---

If you are using a **package-based JRE install** like *Java 8 JRE* via a the custom PPA in a Debian-based distribution, or used *OpenJDK*, the directory will most likely be **/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle** (or whatever version you have chosen). You can find this path set in the **JAVA_HOME** environment variable:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

---

***Manual Download***

---

If you have installed via the *Java JRE/SDK download*, it will be wherever you placed the folder, e.g. */home/**username**/jdk-8u121_1.8.0* (or something similar).

Scripted installs may even add the SDK to */opt/java-8-oracle*, but as of this writing, the Java Install instructions leave the folder placement in your hands.

---

***Android Studio 2.2***

---

Lastly if you are using Android Studio, the SDK is placed where you have set it to place the SDK files downloaded through the Studio's SDK Manager. By going to **File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK**, you can find the SDK location setting at the top with the option to change, and the default folder being **~/Android/Sdk**.

[image: Android Studio SDK Path]

## Setting the SDK Path

Now that we know where the SDK is, it is time to let react-native know.

---

**Option 1: Set with local.properties**

---

This method is very simple, and all that is needed is creating the file *local.properties* in the following folder, where *Project_Folder* is the base of your React-Native application:

Project_Folder/Android/App

In your local.properties, you want to set the variable sdk.dir to the path of your SDK folder:

```
sdk.dir=/home/username/Android/Sdk
```

While this is the easiest way to remedy the issue, it is not the best, especially if you work with multiple projects. For every project, you will have to create this file for every project, and if the folder changes plan on changing this file for each project's local.properties.

Once the file is saved, rerun the **react-native run-android** command.

---

**Option 2: Settings Folders with Environment Variables**

---

The other option is to set the SDK folders to the local environment variables that React-Native looks for by default. To do so, we will add the ANDROID_HOME path. As a bonus we can also add our android tools in the same place. We need to add this to rather the .bash_profile or .profile files in our home directory, which are loaded last, so we can make sure that nothing else is overriding the settings we make. Since these are in your home directory, there is no need to edit with escalated privileges.

```
**$ vim ~/.profile**  (use nano or pico if you prefer)
```

In the file add the following lines replacing the SDK folder with the one you found above. I will be using the Android Studio folder as an example:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="~/Android/Sdk"
export PATH=$PATH:~/Android/Sdk/tools:~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
```

Save the file, then apply the profile settings:

```
$ source ~/.profile
$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/home/dbrown/Android/Sdk
```

If the Sdk folder shows correctly, congratulations! Re-run your react-native command, and watch the app build process continue forward.

---

**If you still have issues**

---

If for some reason you receive the error "**> failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' in: your/sdk/folder**, you need to make sure that the project's build version and the version of the SDK installed match (React-Native defaults to 23.0.1). You can find the default version in **Project_Folder/android/app/build.gradle**, and then searching for **buildToolsVersion**. You can of course change the version from this file, or in Android Studio go to **File > Project Structure** to change the **Project SDK**. I would not suggest changing this version unless you absolutely know what you are doing, otherwise install the SDK version the project is looking for.

Answer (score 12):

This answer is for `MacOs Catalina` user or `zsh` users as your Mac now uses zsh as the default login shell and interactive shell.

If you follow along with the docs of React Native `Setting up the development environment` guide. Then do the following.

Firstly check if `local.properties` file exists or not.
If the file does not exist then create and add the following line.

```
sdk.dir=/Users/<youcomputername>/Library/Android/sdk
```

After doing the above changes now do the following.

1. Open `~/.zshrc` using a code-editor. In my case I use vim

```
vim ~/.zshrc
```

2. Add the following line for the path.

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/<yourcomputername>/Library/Android/sdk"
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
```

> Make sure to add the above line correctly else it will give you a weird error.

4. Save the changes and close the editor.
5. Finally, now compile your changes

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

I get this working in my case. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 11):

You must write correct full path.
Don't use '~/Library/Android/sdk'

```
vi ~/.bashrc

export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/{UserName}/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools

source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 7):

On Ubuntu, where you have to get SDK separately from the Android Studio *strange* the path will work with Android Studio but with React Native, you'll need to create a file name `local.properties`.

For example inn `~/AwesomeProject/android` and insert this line:
`sdk.dir=/path/to/sdk/in/your/computer`

Answer (score 7):

Delete the `local.properties` from the **android** folder in your react project and try it.

I've done this and succeeded.

Answer (score 6):

Check out in your `local.properties` file:

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk
```

if the format is proper or not

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Ubuntu, just go to android directory of your react-native project and create a file called `local.properties` and add android sdk path to it as follow:

```
sdk.dir = /home/[YOUR_USERNAME]/Android/Sdk
```

Answer (score 4):

Copy your system's other android project local.properties and paste in android folder of React-native project it will work.

Comment: Kudos for a crafty and bullet-proof solution ;)

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me .

I am taking Stephen Grider's React Native on Udemy and one of the students posted this in Lecture 50.  Pasted verbatim in the command line (w/o '$' of course).

```
$ export "ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk" >~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Dont do this. it will result in the error `> The SDK directory '/usr/local/opt/android-sdk' does not exist.`

Answer (score 3):

The best solution I can find is as follows:

1. [Download Android Studio and SDK of your choice](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) (Even if you think you don't need it trust me that you would need it to release the apk file and some manual changes to the android code).
2. File > New > Import , point to the location where your react native android project is.
3. If it ask you to download any specific SDK then please download the same. It can ask you to update gradle etc... Please keep on updating where required.
4. If you have an existing Android SDK and you know the version then all you have to do is match that version under build.gradle of your android project.

This is how the gradle file will look like:

[image]

If everything has gone well with your machine setup and you can compile the project using the Android Studio then nothing will stop you to build your app through react-native cli build android command.

With this approach, not only you will solve the problem of SDK, you will also resolve many issues related with your machine setup for Android development. The import will automatically find SDK location and create local.properties. Hence you don't need to worry about manual interventions.

Answer (score 3):

If local.properties file is missing,
 just create one in the "project/android" folder with 
 'sdk.dir=/Users/apple/Library/Android/sdk' and make sure your SDK in on that location.

for creating a file with custom extensions on mac refer the following link

[How do I save a TextEdit (mac) file with a custom extension (.sas)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23976219/how-do-i-save-a-textedit-mac-file-with-a-custom-extension-sas/57946817#57946817)

Answer (score 2):

**For Linux Users**

Your app is not getting the path of android-sdk, so If you are using linux (ubuntu), than you need to add a file named "local.properties" and save it inside the android folder, which is created inside your app folder.

You need to add below line inside local.properties file, which is the path of your android-sdk lies inside your system inside system in order to run the app.

`sdk.dir=/opt/android-sdk/`

save and rerun the command *react-native run-android*

**OR**

you can open terminal, type

**sudo nano ~/.bashrc**

and paste the below path at the end of the file

**export ANDROID_HOME="/opt/android-sdk/"**

and *restart your computer* and run again *react-native run-android* after that.

**Note:- If you put set path in .bashrc file, then you don't even need to create local.properties file.**

Comment: This shouldn't be an hardcoded solution but depends on where Android Studio SDK is been installed. In my case is sdk.dir="pathWhereAndroidSDKisbeeninstalled/Android/Sdk"

Comment: Actually on my side the SDK were installed initially in /root/.
I had to move the /root/Android/Sdk to /usr/Android.
Then I changed the SDK setting in Android Studio to point to the new location
After that I also added export ANDROID_HOME="/usr/Android/Sdk" to ~/.bashrc
I stopped and restarted with npm start and it recognized automatically

Answer (score 2):

If you create and `android studio` project, You can see a `local.properties` file is created inside your project root directory. When you create a react native project, It doesn't create that file for you. So you have to create it manually. And have to add skd dir to it. So create a new file inside android folder ( on root ). and put your sdk path like this 
`sdk.dir=D\:\\Android\\SDK\\android_sdk_studio .` 
**Remember: remove single \ with double. Just like above.**

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to solve this issue:

1. Simple run your react native Android project in the android studio it will automatically generate your *local.properties* file in react native Android project.
2. a. Go to React-native Project -> Android
   b. Create a file *local.properties*
   c. Open the file
   d. Paste your Android SDK path like below

Answer (score 2):

Create a file with the name lcoal.properties in `Android/` and paste the below path.

```
sdk.dir = /Users/jotnosqh/Library/Android/sdk (for linux)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the proper emulator and Android version installed. That solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

In your Project Directory there is a folder called "android" and inside it there is the local.properties file .
Delete the file and the build should run successfully

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mac you need to export your sdk path. just replace Macbook with your system name and then paste into the terminal. "For temporarily use"

> export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/**`MacBook`**/Library/Android/sdk

Answer (score 0):

There are two gradle files, **change the one inside your C:\myapp\android\build.gradle** and not in the parent directory myapp.

**Replace 23.0.1 with your version of Android Build Tool installed in my case 25.0.0**

Run **react-native run-android** to see your app in emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your system's other android project local.properties and paste in android folder of React-native project it will work.

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\paul\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
```

Comment: C\:\\Users\\champika\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk

Answer (score 0):

Just open folder android in project by **Android Studio**.
Android studio create necessary file(local.properties) and download SDK version for run android needed.

Answer (score 0):

I am on Windows and I had to modify sdk path irrespective of having it in PATH env. variable

```
sdk.dir=C:/Users/MY_USERNAME/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk
```

Changed this file:

```
MyProject\android\local.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have misconfigured the environment variables. You have to use (in Windows) the SDK of: `C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`

For more information: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

Select: React Native CLI Quickstart in the Android development environment section in point 3. Configure the `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable

If you do it as you have it right now you must configure each project to use your environment variables and if the project is among several people with their equipment it can cause a problem. If you do it as I have told you, you will not have to configure any project.

Answer (score 0):

If you have android studio installed, simply open the `Project/android` using Android Studio, and it will notify you to switch the SDK location path in the project.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: if you have Android Studio installed, you can open your project’s Android folder in Android Studio. The `local.properties` file is automatically created when Android Studio opens the folder, and your project should build after that.

Open Android Studio
Click “Open an Existing Project”
Choose the “android” folder in your project folder
Press “Open”

Answer (score -2):

After creating the `local.properties` file and you are still having the problem just like I was having.

Press ***Ctrl+S*** to save the file

Yeah, that was a pretty tricky miss.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33948520)