# React Native - java.lang.RuntimeException: SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties

Tags: java, android, react-native

Getting started with React Native. I did install the Android SDK, Java SDK, and Android dependencies. I receive the following error when running a demo app on my terminal.

I do have my Galaxy Emulator running:

```
~ emulator @galaxy
HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
emulator: UpdateChecker: skipped version check
```

Now I run it:

```
~ react-native run-android
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration failure takes precedence.
java.lang.RuntimeException: SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.getAndCheckSdkFolder(SdkHandler.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.getSdkLoader(SdkHandler.java:112)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.initTarget(SdkHandler.java:86)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.ensureTargetSetup(BasePlugin.groovy:507)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.groovy:455)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_createTasks_closure13_closure17.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy:415)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_createTasks_closure13_closure17.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:292)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1015)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.SpanRecorders$2.call(SpanRecorders.groovy:52)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:189)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.SpanRecorders.record(SpanRecorders.groovy:54)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_createTasks_closure13.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy:414)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:292)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1015)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
    at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:40)
    at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:25)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:87)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:31)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:487)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:85)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:90)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:27)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/jonathanbello/Documents/Personal-Projects/Javascript/React-Native/WeatherApp/android/app/build.gradle' line: 102

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug                                                                             option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.565 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

System:
- OSX Yosemite
- node v 5.5

Comment: The same question answered here : [SDK location : stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634352/react-native-android-build-failed-sdk-location-not-found)

Answer (score 12):

In Android Studio: File ->Project Structure -> Android SDK Location

Copy Android SDK Path
[image]

1. In Your Project_Name -> Android -> Create a File local.properties
2. Open local.properties.
3. Write sdk.dir=/Users/Ashok/Library/Android/sdk
4. Save it.
5. from your project root directory `react-native run-android`.

Comment: I was stupid, put the **local.properties** file in the root folder but the **Android** folder. That might be the reason why I had the same error.

Comment: @Ashok.... Daaamn, this should've been part of the facebook getting started tutorial. Thanks a looooot!

Answer (score 7):

Here's how I make react-native work with Android at Mac OSX:

1. Download android studio and update android sdk via it,
   https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads
2. Add PATH in `.base_profile`

   `export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/UserName/Library/Android/sdk
   export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`
3. Put the `local.properties` file inside of `project_name/android/` folder.
4. Edit `local.properties` then add `sdk.dir=/Users/UserName/Library/Android/sdk` in it.
5. Run `android` command to update required packages.
   For RN 0.32, its

   - tools/sdk build tools 23.0.1
   - Android 6.0(API 23)
   - Extras
   - Android Support Library
6. Run android studio or `android avd` command to open a emulator
7. do `react-native run-android`
8. once you seen app's red screen in android, do `react-native start` to trigger the bridge server

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio, follow below steps.

- Go to File > Project structure >
- In SDK Location tab add "location path" and try again.

Comment: I'm not using Android Studio, but downloaded. I'm unable to click on Project Structure.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux without android studio:

First checks: You have already downloaded and unzipped the android SDK and ran the android command to install an actual development SDK?

Still its not found when building and running. Then the problem might be that the file local.properties needs to be inside the same directory as gradle stuff for gradle to find it when building and running adb.

For my project using I needed to put the local.properties file to Myprojectname/android/ folder and it started to work.

As I had unzipped the SDK to Downloads my path in the file is this: sdk.dir=/home/USER/Downloads/android-sdk-linux

Answer (score 0):

Add android studio path to your environment variable

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Add below lines:

```
 export ANDROID_HOME=/YOUR_PATH_TO/android-sdk
 export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
 export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
```

Comment: I have done all this, even created local.properies file but still it doesn't work.