# Build failed with an exception in React Native android

Tags: android, linux, react-native

I am new to React Native.  When I run the project using `react-native run-android` in terminal, `Build failed with an exception` error will display.

I set `android_home` (sdk location) correctly:

```
Error detail

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/sugeivan/react/AwesomeProject/android/app/build.gradle' line: 110

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native - java.lang.RuntimeException: SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35141951/react-native-java-lang-runtimeexception-sdk-location-not-found-define-locati)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build system need to know the exact location of **`SDK`** on your system which contain platform specific tools and source code files to build the project.

seems like your android **sdk** **path** is not set in your **OS** and make sure you have SDK.

1. if there is no **`ANDROID_HOME`** varibale or the sdk path is wrong
   so to check this

goto control panal=> system =>properties 
find environment variable option under advance tab and click on it

if not found
then you need to set the sdk location path in environment variables by adding a new variable as **`"ANDROID_HOME"`** .you can do this in two ways

through terminal follow this link
[this will create new variable and add it to OS environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28296237/set-android-home-environment-variable-in-mac)

and other way is 
goto control panal=> system =>properties 
find environment variable option under advance tab and click on it
create new under user variable 
name will be **`ANDROID_HOME`**
and value will be "path to your sdk folder" 
e.g `C:\android\sdk`

2. if the varible is set then try to add this line in your **`local.properties`** file

*sdk.dir=C:\android\sdk*

Comment: i am using linux, my path in bash >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>export ANDROID_HOME=/home/sugeivan/Android/Sdk/

PATH="~/Android/Sdk/tools:~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:${PATH}" export PATH

Comment: u need to do itlike this

export ANDROID_HOME=/home/user/Android/Sdk  <pathToSDK>
export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/Android/Sdk/tools <path to tool>
from here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256279/how-to-set-android-home-path-in-ubuntu-please-provide-the-steps

and make sure build.gradle files are there in your project
or if nothing works
make sure your sdk path is properly set and then try to create a new project, sdk path loc is required many places in project so sometimes gradle can be little goofy if path wasn't set while creating project

Answer (score 0):

You should set the environment path as:

```
   variable name: ANDROID_HOME
   variable value: F:\android\android-sdk

   You need to restart the Command Prompt (Windows) to apply the new environment variables.

  variable value is your android sdk path.
```

you should also correctly set android studio sdk path by going to:

```
   1. File
   2. Settings
   3. Android SDK-> Android SDK Location: F:\android\android-sdk
 you should update your SDK libraries as mentioned by the react-native official documentation:
```

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.27/docs/getting-started.html