# React Native wont run on Android Device. Missing ANDROID_HOME

Tags: react-native

When I execute **react-native run-android** in the terminal, I get the following:

> JS server already running.
>   Running adb -s HT68X0201778 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
>
> Building and installing the app on the device (cd
>   android && ./gradlew installDebug)... Failed to notify
>   ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration
>   failure takes precedence. java.lang.RuntimeException: SDK location not
>   found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or
>   with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> Where: Build file '........./android/app/build.gradle'
>   line: 110
>
> What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>
> > SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
>
> Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

I have already done the following: Installed  the Android Studio 2.2.3. I checked the boxes in the installer that it said to on the RN website. I installed Marshmallow SDK, AVD, HAXM, and JDK 1.8. I added ANDROID_HOME to /.bashrc and even executed **set ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk** on the terminal. (I double-checked the path.) I am running on react-native-cli version 2.0.1. Operating system is Mac OS Sierra.

I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks! --Anthony

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a file called local.properties and add it to the android folder and then define sdk.dir(The location of your android SDK directory) in my case it is:
*NOTE: you do not need to include it in quotes.*

```
sdk.dir = /home/kbuhiire/Android/Sdk
```

Answer (score 2):

I changed the ANDROID_HOME path from ~/Library/Android/sdk to /Users/myusername/Library/Android/sdk. That did the trick. Refer to [React Native android build failed. SDK location not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634352/react-native-android-build-failed-sdk-location-not-found)