# react-native run-android command failed, but gradlew installDebug work

Tags: android, react-native

I'm using react-native 0.43.3 on OSX.
I tried to running app on Android and get message

```
react-native run-android

Scanning 568 folders for symlinks in /Users/ruci.k/project/mayacrew/supermembers/supermembers/node_modules (5ms)
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

./gradlew installDebug gave me some errors and fixed it all.
Finally build get successed and app is working on Android device.

But `react-native run-android` command still not work.
Only `./gradlew installDebug` command work.

Is there anything can I check to use `react-native run-android` command?

I can't understand how could it happened.

Answer (score 38):

Running

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home"
```

worked for me

Comment: It works for me too! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Giving ERROR
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: Finally! Thanks

Comment: Amazing solution, after hours of research. but can you explain abit what it does. I literally copy pasted without knowing what it does haha

Comment: For some reason it seams that the JAVA_HOME path gets set to an incorrect value. This solution simply sets it to the correct one. FYI it might not the same path for everyone!! It's a good idea to write, for example 
`export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android`
And then press tab a couple of times, selecting the correct path until you get to `...Contents/Home` .
Also a good idea to include this in the .zshrc file (or whatever you're using)

Comment: wow thanks for all the context on why that worked for you

Comment: Try doing `export JAVA_HOME="/usr/libexec/java_home"` instead to fix the errors @ShubhamMishra is getting

Comment: This actually gives me a different error now, same as ShubhamMishra and Brandalf's does not fix.

Answer (score 32):

Run the following command

`chmod 755 android/gradlew`

inside your app root folder
then run

`react-native run-android`

Comment: if I'm using Windows?

Comment: Can you specify what exactly is causing the error and how this command helps?

Comment: This fixed it for me.. as the  error states here it is an acces issue. All chmod does is change the access permissions on that folder @P.Gupta

Comment: Wow!!! Its really helping on iOS and saving my time a lot. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 21):

After you create your react native app ,try

```
sudo chmod -R 777 node-modules
sudo chmod -R 777 android 
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
```

now run

```
react-native run-android
```

Comment: I didn't had to run the last command. Thanks.

Comment: using `sudo chmod -R 777` is risky, and most of the time not need. I encourage you and others to be very carful when you use it. Take it as an advice.

Comment: use sudo chmod -R 777 node_modules instead of sudo chmod -R 777 node-modules

Answer (score 16):

Try removing android,ios folders and then do `react-native upgrade` then try again `react-native run-android` After that if you get an error like

> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

then create a file named local.properties inside the folder

> android

and insert the following line `sdk.dir =/path/to/Android/Sdk` After this everything should be fine

**Note: If you have made some changes in android/ios folder please keep its backup before removing the folders**

Comment: removing the folders and running the above commands simply throws an error that the android folder is now missing. This https://stackoverflow.com/a/61913747/1103592 solved it for me

Answer (score 12):

```
cd android && sudo ./gradlew clean
```

This worked for me. Try it out and let me know if it helps folks

Answer (score 4):

I have faced the same issue when I have imported the project from the GitHub.

**Follow the below steps to run your react-native project in the Android device from the MAC OS**

1. Remove the 'node_modules' folder from the root project.
2. Run the below command in the project root folder.

> npm install

3. Move to the android folder in the project root folder.

   > cd android
4. Run the following commands one after another to give permissions to gradlew file.

> chmod +x ./gradlew
>
> xattr -l ./gradlew
>
> xattr -d com.apple.quarantine ./gradlew

4. Now, come back to project root folder and run the project in android device.

> react-native run-android

Now you can see the launched application on your connected Android device/emulator.

Comment: if i'm using Windows ?

Answer (score 4):

In Ubuntu, I have used this command and it worked for me:

```
    sudo react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, and just opened the project in android studio, and that's all. Solved!

Comment: This works! But this solution is better https://stackoverflow.com/a/66567300/4820421

Answer (score 3):

this issue come from two reasons

**1- Permission issue**

*How to Fix it*

```
sudo react-native run-android
```

Or

```
chmod 755 android/gradlew
```

**2- Mismatch java version with Gradle**

make sure you are using Java 8 as `$JAVA_HOME` environment variable

depending on which terminal you are using to run your code at

> ```
> For zsh shell, export $JAVA_HOME at ~/.zshenv or ~/.zshrc.
> For bash shell, export $JAVA_HOME at ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc.
> ```

get installed JDK by this command

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

example for using zsh

```
vi  ~/.zshrc
// paste the java export inside it 
export JAVA_HOME="JDK_8_Path_from_previous command"
```

to save your change

```
:x
```

make sure your changes applied

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

now for testing

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Answer (score 2):

You must change your **build.gradle**:

```
compileSdkVersion 28  
buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"  
minSdkVersion 16  
targetSdkVersion 27
```

and add this line:

```
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
```

Comment: Where to add `implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"`

Comment: Saularis, I know it's too late but may be it will help to someone, put this line `implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"` in `android/app/build.gradle`

Answer (score 2):

Check whether your emulator is connected or not:

1. set ANDROID_HOME path: `E:\android-sdk-windows`
2. set path `D:C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin;E:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools`

Answer (score 1):

1. go to folder android in terminal
2. gradlew clean
3. run react-native run-android

Answer (score 0):

maybe install watchman?

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10056

Otherwise, for me I actually use 'npm start' inside of the folder. npm will know to run the right command to start react native because it's in a react native directory.

Comment: And as your answer, I try to use 'npm start' and it results same with 'react-native start'. Starting JS server working well, just 'react-native run-android' not worked.

Answer (score 0):

So what i did was to download this jar file from: [1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MHSJx-_0RHRzlrXBLAePKeWKQteke0Um/view?usp=sharing): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MHSJx-_0RHRzlrXBLAePKeWKQteke0Um/view?usp=sharing and placed it inside `android/gradle/wrapper` then i went back to the project directory and did `npm install` i then changed directory to android by doing: `cd android` then i ran the following commands

> chmod +x ./gradlew
>
> xattr -l ./gradlew

Now i went back to the project directory and ran `react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to C:\Users\ [username]
2. Rename or delete ".gradle"
3. Then run "react-native run-android"

Answer (score 0):

So here are the three solution for this bug , from which one will most probably solve your issue :

1: Adding local.properties file in your android folder

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634352/react-native-android-build-failed-sdk-location-not-found

2: Try deleting .gradle file and then build (react-native run-android)

3: Might be possible that under SDK tools NDK(side by side) and CMake are not installed .
Steps for the same is
[Android Studio which include direction for opening sdk manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhQro.png)

> Open android folder in Android Studio
> Click on the SDK Manager (which is at the third position from the top left )

After opening SDK manager you have to go to SDK Tools [Installation image for NDK and CMake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3SDo.png)

> Under SDK Tools select NDK(side by side) and CMake and press the okay button and let the installation complete .
> After the close the Android Studio and react-native run-android.

Answer (score 0):

1 . you should have space in your phone
2 . developer option on
3 . USB debugging option also on
4 . check "adb devices" devices is connected or not

Answer (score 0):

I have to perform these steps to get it running.

- First install dos2unix
- Run dos2unix ./gradlew inside android folder
- then run ./gradlew clean
- at last run react-native run-android.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this had to do with running low on RAM om my Mac.

in gradle.properties put -XX:MaxPermSize=4096

for example like this:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m
```

After that, it runs again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is,

Uninstalling the previous installed app version on the emulator device, and running `react-native run-android` after.

Answer (score 0):

Check the error messages carefully. It will give a clue to what went wrong. In my case, after installing expo in my react-native project, the MainApplication.java got corrupted. I made a comparison with the a backup (you can check an earlier working commit), then removed the erroring lines.

After this, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

as for me working on apple m1 I had to change the path to the following:

export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home"

just a change in the path in case it didn't work with

export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home"