# Can't run react native project project on android device

Tags: android, reactjs, gradle, react-native

This is my first react project. I created the project using `npx react-native init Projectname`. The project created successfully and everything seems ok until when I tried to run the with `react-native` `run-android`, It gives the following error:

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Could not initialize `class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper`
- Try:
  Run with `--stacktrace` option to get the stack trace. Run with `--info` or `--debug` option to get more log output. Run with `--scan` to get full insights.
- *Get more help at https://help.gradle.org*

BUILD FAILED in 2s:

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

---

My android device is connected with a USB but then also it says that the android device is not connected. I also did  `react-native start` in another cmd window and run `react-native run-android` in another window but it didn't work.

Comment: `adb is not recognized as an internal or external command` error shows that you need to Add platform-tools to Path , platform tools can be found here `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools` in windows

Comment: you shouldn't install react-native cli globally if you have installed it globally it might create some problem it is clearly mentioned in https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Comment: what version of gradle and groovy are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How solve (Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache) issue in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60844245/how-solve-could-not-initialize-class-org-codehaus-groovy-reflection-reflectionc)

Comment: added  platform-tools to path, removed react-native package but still the build gets failed.

Comment: what is error now ?