# Java problems with Android Studio

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio

I'm following a Flutter course with The App Brewery and I'm starting to have problems recently with Java at Android Studio that I hadn't got before.

First of all I was requested to install JDK I don't know why because I did 15% of the course with no problem with java.

And now I'm receiving this message when trying to complie:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache
```

The code for the app should be ok because is a non modified Git repository directly from the course.

Any idea?

Comment: Check this answer for ReactJS : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60967507/3780625

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61289461/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-org-codehaus-groovy-v) help?

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.