# Android SDK cannot be found by flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I have installed [`flutter` through AUR.](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/flutter/) I also have `aur/android-sdk 26.0.2-1` installed. When I run `flutter run` I get:

```
Warning! This package referenced a Flutter repository via the .packages file that is
no longer available. The repository from which the 'flutter' tool is currently
executing will be used instead.
  running Flutter tool: /home/dair/.flutter-sdk
  previous reference  : /home/dair/flutter
This can happen if you deleted or moved your copy of the Flutter repository, or
if it was on a volume that is no longer mounted or has been mounted at a
different location. Please check your system path to verify that you are running
the expected version (run 'flutter --version' to see which flutter is on your path).

Unable to locate a development device; please run 'flutter doctor' for information about installing additional components.
```

Firstly, I ran `flutter --version`, and received:

```
Flutter • channel alpha • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision e2f54df5ab (9 days ago) • 2017-06-02 10:43:54 -0700
Engine • revision 1f2aa07571
Tools • Dart 1.24.0-dev.3.0
```

Not sure what exactly it means by "to see which flutter is on your path". Next I ran `flutter doctor` and got:

```
[✓] Flutter (on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8, channel alpha)
    • Flutter at /home/christopher/.flutter-sdk
    • Framework revision e2f54df5ab (9 days ago), 2017-06-02 10:43:54 -0700
    • Engine revision 1f2aa07571
    • Tools Dart version 1.24.0-dev.3.0

[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ ANDROID_HOME = /opt/android-sdk
      but Android SDK not found at this location.

[✓] Android Studio (version 2.3)
    • Android Studio at /usr/local/android-studio
    • Gradle version 3.2
    • Java version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-release-b06)

[✓] Connected devices
    • None
```

However, if I cd into `/opt/android-sdk` I get:

```
➜  ~ cd /opt/android-sdk 
➜  android-sdk ls
add-ons  build-tools  emulator  platforms  tools
```

So it looks like it is there. The closest question I could find is this one: [React Native android build failed. SDK location not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634352/react-native-android-build-failed-sdk-location-not-found) but it seems to be using Mac as opposed to arch as well as some other differences. How can I resolve the `flutter doctor` and have my app run?

Answer (score 132):

I was running with the same problem when I was trying the `flutter doctor` command:

[image]

The problem is a little clear, it's occurring because the flutter is not founding the path for your Android SDK.

There are two ways to solve it:

- You can solve this issue setting only for your current terminal instance the SDK path with the following commands:

  `flutter config --android-sdk /path/to/android/sdk`

  `flutter config --android-studio-dir /path/to/android/studio`
- Or to save it forever, exporting the `ANDROID_HOME` with your Android sdk path.

I solved it by exporting the `ANDROID_HOME` on my machine (Arch Linux, but this works for any Unix instance).

This will solve your issue, But you can need the `sdk`, `platform-tools`, `tools` and the `ndk-build` paths too (of course, everything needs to be installed first) on my profile file (in my case the `.zshrc` file, the same can be done on your `.bashrc` and etc.):

```
#SDK exporting - this will solve your issue
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/{user}/Android/Sdk 

#Tools exporting - it can be need in your case
export PATH=/home/{user}/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=/home/{user}/Android/Sdk/tools:$PATH
export PATH=/home/{user}/Android/ndk-build:$PATH

#Flutter binary exporting
export PATH=/home/{user}/flutter/bin:$PATH
```

Then, I reloaded my profile file (that in my is the `.zshrc` file, use your file in your case .eg `.bashrc`):

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

After that, the `flutter doctor` will run properly.

[image]

Comment: `flutter config --android-sdk /path/to/android/sdk` This worked for me. Thanks

Comment: I added the ANDROID_HOME but flutter couldnt locate it. I did alot of searches in github too but none of them resulted.

Comment: @Mahdi-Jafaree did you edit the correct file for your shell? Which OS are you using?

Comment: Added ANDROID_HOME to path first, didn't work. Then tried     flutter config --android-sdk /path/to/android/sdk  and it worked. Thanks a million times.

Comment: flutter config --android-sdk /path/to/android/sdk, when i did this the android studio warn me  • Android Studio at /path/to/android/studio/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    ✗ Android Studio not found at /path/to/android/studio/Contents
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.

Answer (score 65):

If you're using Android Studio 3, you can configure your platform SDK by going to <kbd>File</kbd> -> <kbd>Project structure</kbd> and choose your platform SDK.

Hope this works for you.

[image]

Answer (score 36):

I have solved this problem by the following command
`flutter config --android-sdk <sdk-location>`
Where  is the location for your sdk. If you're on windows make sure to use double quotes.

Answer (score 25):

**For Windows:**
Inside Android Studio,
get path from : Apprearance & Behaviour > System Settings > Android SDK > Android SDK path

Make sure your path does not contain any **spaces** in them, if you have edit path and re-install sdk to a different location.

After that,

```
flutter config --android-sdk {path}
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

You are set!

Comment: For me, the issue is that the path to Android SDK contains spaces. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 11):

To get the Android SDK path
- Open Flutter project in Android Studio
- Go to File > Project Structure > SDK Location. Copy the location

To set the Android SDK path
- Type in terminal `flutter config --android-sdk /path/that/you/just/copied`

Comment: Am having the same issue for ios, it was working properly, but now
whenever I run flutter doctor, I get this result

 ✗ CocoaPods not installed.
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To install:
        sudo gem install cocoapods

and 'sudo gem install cocoapods' never works

Answer (score 10):

i have solved! 
i put my android SDK before in F:/androidsdk
so when i run "**flutter config**" android sdk doesnt linked.
To link flutter wiht android sdk just type command below:

```
flutter config --android-sdk /path/to/android/sdk
```

i just change with this

```
flutter config --android-sdk F:/androidsdk
```

i hope this is working.

Comment: Thank you.
before I used (\) in this line and emit error , but I use (/) and issue is fix.

Answer (score 8):

I suffered alot trying to find a solution to it and finally I found the solution by configuring the project SDK
File -> Project structure then choose sdk platform.

Answer (score 5):

Go to the project structure and make sure the sdk version is selected. [image: Project Structure Image]

Answer (score 3):

Flutter [requires](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/android/android_sdk.dart#L41) the Android SDK platform tools so that it can use the `adb` command line tool.

It looks like you've installed the Android SDK but you haven't installed the platform tools yet.

Here is the [android-sdk-platform-tools](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/android-sdk-platform-tools/) Aur package for arch and a [guide](http://www.archlinuxuser.com/2013/01/how-to-install-android-sdk-android.html) for how to install it.

Possibly the error message could be improved to indicate that we are actually missing the Android SDK platform tools rather than the Android SDK itself. If you want to, feel free to send a pull request or open an [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new).

Comment: Ok thanks! This seems to get me a bit further. I'm going to do a little more debugging to see if I can resolve it completely before I accept. Android studio had a few problems the past couple of days on arch. Typical rolling release model haha.

Answer (score 3):

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir <path where android studio is installed>
```

In my case it was `"C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"`

try with double quotes in the command( I tried with double quotes, which might be necessary if there is space in the path)

Source: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup

Answer (score 1):

It is saying that your project is using two different path of flutter-sdk. There are two place where sdk paths are defined.

1. Setting (*Setting > Language&Frameworks > Flutter > Flutter SDK path*)

[image]

2. **local.properties** in your root folder

[image]

These both place should contain same path to sdk.Compile with `flutter run` !! done !!

Answer (score 1):

The solution at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15114#issuecomment-376582281 worked for me, this worked after adding $ANDROID_SDK_PATH\platform-tools to user path variable.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the Android SDK command-line tools were missing, i.e. installing Android Studio did not install the command-line tools automatically.

I had to run Android studio and use the included SDK manager to install the *Android SDK Command-line Tools*

Start *Android Studio*, select *More Actions...* > *SDK Manager*, select the *SDK Tools* tab, make sure to check *Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)*, click *Apply*. This will install the Android SDK command-line tools.

After that, `flutter doctor` completed successfully. No need to set `flutter config --android-sdk ...` etc.

```
$ uname -a
Linux x220 6.1.0-7-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.20-2 (2023-04-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

I've set up my Android SDK manually on Windows 10 with the command line, I think this not change a lot in Linux, and I was able to solve this kind of errors while I tried to set up my development environment, if you want to solve it as I did, just follow the next steps that I posted in a GitHub Comment in a related issue:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19805#issuecomment-478306166

**I hope this can help anyone need it! Bye!**

Answer (score 0):

in ***environment variables*** 
make
 **Variables**: `ANDROID_HOME`

and add path of **SDK** get from 
Andriod stideo --> settings --> SDK Coppy the **Path** examlpe

**:C:\Users\Omar\AppData\Local\Android**

Add the SDK path in variables Value: `C:\Users\Omar\AppData\Local\Android`

Next Step: Add 2 value in **path variables** :

```
 %ANDROID_HOME%\tools 

%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

**For macOS Catalina:**
If you have installed android sdk to a custom location (say `/Users/your_username/dev/android/sdk`) then follow these steps (NOTE: You must change the location according to your sdk location):

1. Open zshrc file

   `nano ~/.zshrc`
2. Add the following to the zshrc file

   `export ANDROID_HOME=Users/your_username/dev/android/sdk`
   `export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$ANDROID_HOME`
   `export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=$HOME/.android/avd`
3. Save and close nano using `Ctrl+x`, when prompted type `y`
4. Source your zshrc file using

   `source $HOME/.zshrc`
5. You can check whether your problem is fixed by typing the following in a terminal window. You should get the sdk path as your output

   `echo $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows 10 Version 2004**

I added a user environment variable named `ANDROID_HOME` and value is `{SDK-PATH}\build-tools\{SDK-VERSION}`. You have to replace SDK-PATH and SDK-VERSION for your custom values.

And I appended another value named `%ANDROID_HOME%` to system `PATH` variable.

Then it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

for me, it was very simple.

this kind of issue usually happens if IDE unable to load `SDK`.

so to solve this follow below steps:

goto `file menu` -> `project structure` -> `project settings` -> `select "project"`

now set Android SDK path with existing java version.

then select "modules" and configure Android SDK and click on apply and then click ok.

now we may find both ios and android emulators to run your flutter app on both devices.

Answer (score 0):

You Can follow the first answer above. I would like to add a tip. If you are on windows and installed sdk on a path that requires admin rights to modify, then flutter doctor might fail to recognise the sdk. Copy the sdk folder to another non-admin location and then run flutter config --android-sdk  command.

Comment: This should be a comment on the 1st answer rather than being another answer.

Comment: I  need 50 reputations for that. I will definitely move this post to comment once I get there. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

#### Windows command to fix SDK path

As mentioned above by others, using the below command works:

`flutter config --android-sdk /path/to/android/sdk`

Remember to put quotes in the **/path/to/android/sdk**

Example: `flutter config --android-sdk "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk"`

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows 10 (without Android Studio) I noticed that folder '***sdk***/build-tools' is empty. Then I solved this problem by executing:

```
sdkmanager build-tools;30.0.3
```

where 'build-tools;30.0.3' was obtained in an output of "sdkmanager --list >list.txt" command.

And, after **build-tools**'s installation **the error** "*Android SDK cannot be found by flutter*" **was solved** too!

PS. It is absolutely essential to read carefully the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line) (there were although another mistakes by me)

PS.PS. The log (for illustration):

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1697], locale ru-UA)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    X Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set ANDROID_HOME to that location.
      You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.

    X No valid Android SDK platforms found in d:/Android\SDK\platforms. Candidates were:
        - android-13
        - android-19
        - android-23
        - android-29
[!] Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    X android-studio-dir = d:\Android
    X Unable to find bundled Java version.
[√] VS Code (version 1.53.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.

C:\Users\Леон>sdkmanager build-tools;30.0.3

[=======================================] 100% Unzipping... android-11/renderscr
C:\Users\Леон>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1697], locale ru-UA)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[!] Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    X android-studio-dir = d:\Android
    X Unable to find bundled Java version.
[√] VS Code (version 1.53.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.

C:\Users\Леон>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error. Adding Flutter path of extracted flutter sdk till flutter fixed it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We need to fix this in the tool. You can work around this locally by running `flutter config --android-studio-dir='C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio'` , which you can check with explorer. For me this path is `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have to accept the android licenses

run this command in the terminal or android studio terminal

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to write my experience here on a mac.  The real difference to the other answers is that I was confused as to where the installs were, where they should be found and also how confusion was caused by multiple versions of both Android Studio & the sdk existing on my mac.

You to need find two main directories; the sdk location and the installation directory of Android Studio.

## sdk

The sdk seemed to have been installed twice and referenced in different places.  One of which was installed by `brew` so I uninstalled that one.  The one I ended up referencing is the following.  I think that is the proper location on a mac (don't use brew)

```
/Users/myusername/Library/Android/sdk/
```

### sdk references

Run this command

```
flutter config --android-sdk sdk_path_here
```

and set these environment & path variables

```
export ANDROID_HOME=sdk_path_here 
export PATH=sdk_path_here/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=sdk_path_here/tools:$PATH
```

## Android Studio reference

Again there were multiple installs and multiple locations of Android Studio.  You may have installed yours manually and it would be installed in the following location

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app
```

but I had updated to the JetBrains Toolbox so mine was installed there (I uninstalled the other version of Studio).  The one I referenced was

```
/Users/yourusername/Applications/JetBrains\ Toolbox/Android\ Studio.app
```

So I ran the following to set the Android Studio location

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir=/Users/yourusername/Applications/JetBrains\ Toolbox/Android\ Studio.app
```

After that I still was presented with an error but I restarted my whole machine, deleted previously created AVDs in Studio's Device Manager and then everything did indeed work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue and solved it with these simple steps:

1. Open Android Studio.
2. In the top navigation bar, click Tools -> Android SDK.
3. Copy the Android SDK location path, for example /Users/yourname/Library/Android/sdk
4. Click 'Edit' next to the Android SDK location.
5. Check Android SDK option/s (this might already be pre-selected).
6. Click 'next' then continue installation.
7. Restart Android Studio.
8. Open the Android Studio terminal and command `flutter config --android-sdk pastetheAndroidSDKlocationpathhere`.
9. Run `flutter doctor`.