# Alternative methods for rebuilding flutter tools?

Tags: android, flutter

I recently asked [this question about Flutter.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44485848/android-sdk-cannot-be-found-by-flutter) Currently, the answer now gives a different error and, as the answer states, I might want to look at [this segment of the code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/android/android_sdk.dart#L41). So, I decide to fork the repo and begin my investigation. I currently just want to print out a couple of values in the section to figure out what is going on. To see what the program thinks I have, and what it doesn't think I have. I added a couple of `printTrace` statements and now I want to rebuild the project.

I went to [`CONTRIBUTING.md`](https://github.com/thyrgle/flutter/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) and found this:

> The flutter tools itself is built when you run `flutter` for the first
>   time and each time you run `flutter upgrade`. If you want to alter and
>   re-test the tool's behavior itself, locally commit your tool changes
>   in git and the tool will be rebuilt from Dart sources in
>   `packages/flutter_tools` the next time you run `flutter`.

I don't want to exactly "change" anything at the moment, just print out some values and figure out what is going on. The issue is, doing these debugging changes forces me to do a commit. Is there a way to rebuild flutter tools without making a commit?

Answer (score 9):

You can force the Flutter tools to rebuild by removing the build stamp. For example, if your Flutter install is in `~/.flutter-sdk`, you can run

```
rm ~/.flutter-sdk/bin/cache/flutter_tools.stamp
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this worked. I tried adding a message that says "Hi" at [this line](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/android/android_workflow.dart#L94) I first deleted one file from the cache then slowly deleted every file from the cache to see if it would rebuild, but I never saw a "Hi" message or any other indication of rebuilding. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I added a print statement to the first line of main in executable.dart and it worked for me. When you say "flutter doctor" it should say "Building flutter tool..." then "hi"