# Flutter no devices detected even the simulator is on

Tags: flutter

I am a totally rookie in flutter project development and recently i have run into a tech issue that the flutter can not detect the android simulator even the simulator is on ;
The issue as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSVPx.jpg)

```
Flutter console:
F:\Developer\demo>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.7.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.228], locale zh-CN)
    • Flutter version 0.7.3 at D:\flutter_windows_v0.7.3-beta\flutter
    • Framework revision 3b309bda07 (3 months ago), 2018-08-28 12:39:24 -0700
    • Engine revision af42b6dc95
    • Dart version 2.1.0-dev.1.0.flutter-ccb16f7282

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at D:\Android\android-sdk-windows
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = D:\Android\android-sdk-windows
    • Java binary at: D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    • Android Studio at D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 28.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 173.4700
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)

[!] Connected devices
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

So, is there anything i am going wrong?

Comment: Does this happen even if you start the Android simulator via `flutter emulators launch`?

Comment: @jamesdlin yes, it does;

Comment: I think it's worth to upgrade flutter and try again...

Comment: See also https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/2084

Comment: the flutter you have installed (v.0.7.3) is too old. The current stable version is v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable. Try to update flutter first

Comment: You are using beta version...upgrade it to stable version

Answer (score 1):

First check if your devices were listed:

> In terminal, run the `flutter devices` command to verify that Flutter
> recognizes your connected Android device.

You can follow the installation guide provided in the Flutter documentation:

[Windows set-up](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#set-up-your-android-device)

> [Install Android
> Studio](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#install-android-studio)
>
> 1. Download and install [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio).
> 2. Start Android Studio, and go through the ‘Android Studio Setup Wizard’. This installs the latest Android SDK, Android SDK
>    Command-line Tools, and Android SDK Build-Tools, which are required by
>    Flutter when developing for Android.
>
> [Set up your Android
> device](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#set-up-your-android-device)
>
> To prepare to run and test your Flutter app on an Android device, you
> need an Android device running Android 4.1 (API level 16) or higher.
>
> 1. Enable **Developer options** and **USB debugging** on your device. Detailed instructions are available in the [Android
>    documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options).
> 2. Windows-only: Install the [Google USB Driver](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb).
> 3. Using a USB cable, plug your phone into your computer. If prompted on your device, authorize your computer to access your device.
> 4. n the terminal, run the `flutter devices` command to verify that Flutter recognizes your connected Android device. By default, Flutter
>    uses the version of the Android SDK where your `adb` tool is based. If
>    you want Flutter to use a different installation of the Android SDK,
>    you must set the `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` environment variable to that
>    installation directory.
>
> [Set up the Android
> emulator](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#set-up-the-android-emulator)
>
> To prepare to run and test your Flutter app on the Android emulator,
> follow these steps:
>
> 1. Enable [VM
>    acceleration](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration)
>    on your machine.
> 2. Launch **Android Studio**, click the **AVD Manager** icon, and select **Create
>    Virtual Device…**
>
>    - In older versions of Android Studio, you should instead launch **Android Studio > Tools > Android > AVD Manager** and select **Create Virtual Device…**. (The **Android** submenu is only present when
>      inside an Android project.)
>    - If you do not have a project open, you can choose **Configure > AVD Manager** and select **Create Virtual Device…**
> 3. Choose a device definition and select **Next**.
> 4. Select one or more system images for the Android versions you want to emulate, and select **Next**. An *x86* or *x86_64* image is
>    recommended.
> 5. Under Emulated Performance, select **Hardware - GLES 2.0** to enable [hardware
>    acceleration](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration).
> 6. Verify the AVD configuration is correct, and select **Finish**.
>
>    For details on the above steps, see [Managing AVDs](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds).
> 7. In Android Virtual Device Manager, click **Run** in the toolbar. The emulator starts up and displays the default canvas for your
>    selected OS version and device.

Try to check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49045393/flutter-run-no-connected-devices) as well. It is related to your question.