# How to test my Flutter app on my phone? With vscode

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Good Morning,

I am having a problem testing my Flutter applications for lack of memory. My computer only has 4GB of RAM and I can't open the emulator for lack of memory, can anyone help me how can I test the app right on my mobile phone?

Comment: There is already an answer to your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54526682/10228714

Comment: what do you have problems with? your phone is not detected or something else?

Comment: I have already enabled debug mode ... But it is not detected.

Comment: @rodrigoleite89 Check for error using `flutter doctor -v`

Answer (score 17):

You may need to configure Android toolchain (Step 6 to 12).

1. Install VSCode
2. Install VSCode plugins **flutter** and **dart**
3. Close VSCode
4. Download [Flutter SDK](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install)
5. Unzip and Update environment path variable with "...\FlutterSDK\bin"
6. Download [sdk-tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#command-tools)
7. Create an folder anywhere with name "AndroidSDK" (or any other name)
8. Extract downloaded **sdk-tools** to "AndroidSDK"
9. Open command prompt at "...\AndroidSDK\tools\bin"
10. Install **platform-tools** using the following command
    `sdkmanager platform-tools`
11. Install corresponding **platform** and **build-tools** for your mobile device.

> Example: If your device is Android 9 (Which is Android Pie and API level is 28), then commands are

1. `sdkmanager platforms;android-28` (Use `sdkmanager --list` to see all packages available).
2. `sdkmanager build-tools;28.0.3` (Use `sdkmanager --list` to see all packages available).
3. Update Environment path variable with "...\AndroidSDK\platform-tools"
4. Now Open New Command prompt
5. Run `Flutter doctor -v` to check for any issues (You may have to accept android-licences).

> flutter doctor --android-licenses
> 16. Now Open VSCode
> 17. Create Flutter project (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> then type "Flutter: New Project")
> Note*: Internet connection is required (or)
> Open Existing Flutter Project folder
> 18. Connect your android device (Debugging mode should be enabled in the developer options)
> 19. You can see connected device in VSCode at bottom-right corner
> 20. Press F5 to run or use "Flutter run" command

Comment: For the impatient, see **Step 18**

Comment: `18. You can see connected device in VSCode at bottom-right corner` there is no device found at bottom-right corner of VSCode. any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

1. Connect your device via USB cable.
2. Enable *Developer options* on your device.
3. Inside *Developer options* enable everything related to USB debugging: USB  debugging, Install via USB, USB debugging (Security settings)

If everything is OK, you should see your phone in the list of available devices:

[image]

Choose it (it will be displayed at the bottom bar of VS Code)
[image]

and Run/Debug as usual.

Answer (score -1):

If you have android studio installed then:
Go to C:\Users<User>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
Copy folders: platform, platform-tools
Past folder into flutter SDK folder.
connect your device to computer and it will automatically detected.
It worked for me.