# Can I test my Flutter application in a real apple device without apple developer account, and if so how do I do it?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I've read the following [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54444538/how-do-i-run-test-my-flutter-app-on-a-real-device) and [Article](https://ionicframework.com/blog/deploying-to-a-device-without-an-apple-developer-account/). The first SO Question says I need to have an apple developer account to test my application on a real IOS device, however I do not think the 100$ investment to get an apple developer account is worth it. So the Article states that I can deploy it using xcode but the article is targetted for Ionic users. I however, am not an Ionic developer but I am a Flutter developer.

What I want to know is if the Article is feasible for Flutter, and is the minimum iOS version 9.0. Any help would be appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also test on real device without apple paid developer program(you need to add free iclocud id in xcode).
do 'flutter run' on your mac with iphone connected and app will work on real device (if not working run'flutter doctor' and see is your iphone showing i connected devices)
usually what i do is first run on simulator with flutter run which builds ios files then i goto flutter-project-directory/ios/ open any file by double click it will show open ios module in xcode click it. now you can run or upload app to testflight/appstore like we do with native IOS app.

Comment: What if I need to have the .ipa file jut to distribute it to other people?

Comment: Will this work on any iPhone, or only for the person wityh the iCloud account? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Flutter is supported down to iOS 8.0. I think you can test on a Simulator without an account at all, and you just need an Apple account and an iOS device to test on a real device and build the app. You pay the 100$/year to upload on the App Store.

Comment: So I just need to follow the article, or do you have any other articles/tutorials that you have followed? Can you kindly share it to me? Thank you very much

Comment: I followed [Flutter's documentation on macOS install](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos).

Comment: What I meant was, an article to test my app on a real device

Comment: It has a "Deploy to iOS devices" section.