# how can I download my flutter app to my iPhone without using the App Store?

Tags: iphone, xcode, flutter

How can I download my flutter app to my iPhone without putting it in the App Store?

I can run my flutter app on my iPhone in debug mode via usb or wifi but I want to be able to use it without these restrictions.  Is this possible?

Edit:
What are the steps to create a .ipa file to then be loaded onto my phone?

Comment: firebase app distribution

Comment: Thanks.  Used firebase but hadn't heard of this feature.  Looks super useful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I test my Flutter application in a real apple device without apple developer account, and if so how do I do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59587950/can-i-test-my-flutter-application-in-a-real-apple-device-without-apple-developer)

Comment: It is useful, however I think other people might find Jscti's comment about 'firebase app distribution' useful.  Also I am running into trouble creating the .ipa file.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an archive and distribute the app then you will find **app_name.ipa** file then you are able to install the app using itune

Comment: Thanks (and sorry if this is a dumb question).  But what does it mean to archive and distribute your app?  (I just want to use it for personal use btw).

Comment: to create an .ipa file you have to make the archive after that you are able to make the .ipa when you distribute the app file then you are able to install it directly using itune

Comment: so would the command: flutter build ios --debug work?

Comment: ya it works.
For creating .ipa in Xcode "Open the Product menu and choose Archive".

Comment: I am having trouble creating the .ipa file.  However if you edit your answer to give a brief description on how to create the .ipa file, and then how to upload from itunes I will accept your answer.

Comment: You need to open project in xcode then create a archive file. Go to Product menu and choose archive once it will be created go to the windows menu and open Organizer window you will find archive then distribute this archive it create .ipa file.

Comment: @Technomancy - he's asked what you mean by "distribute" it a million times. Answer.