# Can't enable Data Binding in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle, android-databinding

I've recently started developing using Kotlin. I've just learnt about data binding, but I'm not able to enable data binding.

I searched on the internet and it was pretty clear at majority of places that I had to enable it explicitly using "kapt" plugin of kotlin and update the dependencies.

So, I applied as it was recommended.

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
   ...
   dataBinding {
       enabled true
   }
}


dependencies {
   ...
   kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.6.3'
}
```

The error is :

> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.

  > A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
  >   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

I have Android gradle plugin version 3.6.3 and gradle version 5.6.4.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run/test my Flutter app on a real device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54444538/how-do-i-run-test-my-flutter-app-on-a-real-device)

Comment: The dependancy may not be needed.

Comment: I tried it on both, the AVD manager android studio provides and my android device too, still same error. I feel that the problem lies somewhere in the plugin thing, still can't figure out

Comment: Tried it without dependency too, still didn't work