# Real Iphone on android studio FLUTTER

Tags: android, ios, iphone, android-studio, flutter

in android studio (windows)

its possible connect a real iphone for test flutter app?

how?

[image]

xCode is aviable only on macos

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run/test my Flutter app on a real device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54444538/how-do-i-run-test-my-flutter-app-on-a-real-device)

Comment: Xcode is only macos

Comment: whats the output of `flutter devices [-v]` command?

Comment: 1 connected device:

AOSP on IA Emulator • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)

Comment: I don't think you can use any Apple device on windows in Flutter.

Comment: Yes, if you use a virtual machine [How to use remote access to Codemagic virtual MacOS build machine](https://blog.codemagic.io/remote-access-to-virtual-mac-build-machine/)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, but you can use CI/CD like Codemagic, Github Actions to test your app and build ipa, which can be uploaded to AppStore via Transporter from a Mac