# Finished coding my app on Flutter in Android Studio on my MacBook, how to I use it on android phone/ iphone/ ipad?

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, flutter

New to coding community, not sure what's the correct vocabulary for this but I have finished coding my app on Flutter in the Android Studio on my MacBook, it's testing well in simulators, now I want to turn it into a real app that I can click on on my android phone or iphone.

How do I go about to "render"/finish/deploy? my app, and afterward, how do I send it to an android phone and an iPhone/iPad?

Thank you

Comment: See: https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android and https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios

Comment: This should answer your question :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54444538/how-do-i-run-test-my-flutter-app-on-a-real-device  ,  to get more info about getting release version of your app visit official flutter docs for android : https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android   and for iOS : https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios

Comment: @gladiator That first link was helpful but it sounded like the answer only help if you only want to test it on a device, what if I think it's ready to be a real app and want the app to run on the android/iPad device on its own without connecting to the MacBook?

Comment: @mrwuscience I think what you want is release build of your flutter app . In my previous comment I have added links to the official flutter doc explaining how to get the same . Please read them carefully .