# My iPhone won't show up in "Execution List" on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile, kmm

I'm trying my hand at Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile, and am trying to run the demo app on an iPhone. I am able to run it easily on the iPhone Simulator from Android Studio itself, but if I connect my real iPhone to the MacBook, I am unable to see it in the "Execution Target" list on Android Studio.

[image]

Please note that if I open the project using Xcode, I am able to run it on the real iPhone. Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: this might be of a little help :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54444538/how-do-i-run-test-my-flutter-app-on-a-real-device

Comment: Hi, is this question still relevant? There was a couple of KMM Plugin releases, maybe the problem was fixed already.