# Android device not recognized by flutter when installing app

Tags: android, flutter

I've finished the v1.0 of my app and I would like to install it on my phone for daily use (I'm following the docs [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#build-an-apk)).
I built the apk using `flutter build apk --split-per-abi`
I then connected my phone* to my pc and ran `flutter install` but got "No target device connected".

Do I have to follow the steps given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54526682/12356589) answer, even if I just want to install the release version of the app?
Does it have to do with my phone being a Huawei?

Also, I've not gone through the steps of signing my app as I don't intend on publishing it.

*Huawei P30 running Android 10

Comment: Just do it manually. Copy the apk from your system to android and install it

Comment: yea but in which folder?

Comment: {YourAppPath}\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk

Comment: and how would I update it then?

Comment: Build in same fashion and just copy to device and install it.