# Xcode/Flutter devices error: iPhone is busy: Preparing the watch for development via

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

When running:

```
flutter devices
```

I get:

```
• Error: MyPhoneName’s iPhone is busy: Preparing the watch for development via MyPhoneName’s iPhone. Xcode will continue when MyPhoneName’s iPhone is
  finished. (code -10)
```

Is there some old log file or something, containing this error that I can delete?

I found [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/691452) one, so maybe it is simply Apple that needs to do something.

Comment: I have similar issue and for me it was an issue with Signing. 
I solved opening the Xcode project Runner.xcworkspace at Folder "ios" and updating Signing information on Xcode: clicking in "Runner" -> Tap "Signing & Capabilities" and configure my personal account as "Team".

PS: My iPhone use same Apple ID that I configured as "Team"
PS 2: some feature of Apple required a paid account on Apple Developer Program.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run/test my Flutter app on a real device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54444538/how-do-i-run-test-my-flutter-app-on-a-real-device)

Comment: I just had this same problem and following directions for iOS in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54526682/13376511) worked for me. Just make sure you're adding your Apple ID as the Team in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation. The error was due to "Developer Mode" not being turned on. When I went to the "Privacy & Security" section in "Settings" and turned on developer mode, my phone restarted and the problem was solved.

I hope it works for you.