# can i create android and ios applications with flutter without android emulator , with just flutter sdk and vscode and browser

Tags: flutter

I learned dart and I want to access flutter, but I was surprised by android studio because my computer is weak.so,can i create android and apple applications with flutter without android emulator , with just flutter pack and vs code and browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only work with simple UI widgets yes you can use the embedded development tools within the browser to get the dimensions of the device you working on like so[image: How to use devtools to open panels]

But, most of the cases there are libraries work differently according to the platform so it might work with the web but not with android or iphone and you can not test it without the actual device.

And yes VS code is a very good with flutter and might be better than android studio but it won`t make the difference you expected, in my opinion what make it faster is to use an actual device for testing and not using the emulator, also don't use a lot of application along side with the IDE, like if you are using spotify, listening to youtube video or following a tutorial just use your phone because browsers as bad as emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a text editor and the command line tools to build flutter apps and test them on a real device.

I wouldn't recommend it though.

You could give VSCode a try as it is a more lightweight environment.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer should handle testing on a real device, which requires only a USB cable. Accessing the application in the browser would probably eat a lot more memory. You can read about how to use the real device with flutter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54526682/12964903).