# problem to connect my device with flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I have xiaomi redmi note 4
Usb depegging is on 
But when I try to run flutter doctor i have this issue

```
C:\Users\joybank>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 
10.0.16299.251], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 
28.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.3)
[!] Connected device

! Doctor found issues in 1 categoryp
```

Comment: check if you have the device with 'Media (UTP, File Transfer)' on your phone. It's required to load the Flutter app onto the device.

Comment: How to check that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [flutter run: No connected devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49045393/flutter-run-no-connected-devices)

Comment: It should be on the screen when you connect the phone and click the notification. It asks you whether it's for file transfer or charging.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the [USB Driver for Android](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb) as mentioned in this [guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos#set-up-your-android-device). If the driver has been installed previously, try reinstalling it again and run `flutter devices` on your terminal to check if Flutter recognizes the connected Android device.