# Connecting Device in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, flutter

[image]Can't connect a virtual device in flutter app in IntelliJ IDEA.

After setting up win 10 and installing IntelliJ community edition 1/2019, flutter and  dart plugins, and a virtual device with android pie, IntelliJ can't feel the virtual device although it's working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [flutter run: No connected devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49045393/flutter-run-no-connected-devices)

Comment: Did you check this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49055266/5565834

Comment: what's the output of `flutter doctor` when your virtual device is running ?