# I have trouble building APK from a flutter project

Tags: android-studio

I made my app called county in flutter. which counts the number of taps.When I Completed, I tried to build the apk using 'flutter build apk' in android studio project terminal. I am encountered with errors.

While consulting flutter Doctor----------

```
D:\Gowtham\AppDev\Projects\county>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.0)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

---

Do i need Device connected to build APK?

While Building APK-----------------------------------------------

```
D:\Gowtham\AppDev\Projects\county>flutter build apk
Initializing gradle...                                              1.2s
Resolving dependencies...
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "D:\Gowtham\AppDev\Projects\county\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

> Configure project :app
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 28 in C:\Users\Blinko\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
License for package Android SDK Platform 28 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 28 (revision: 6)".
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Platform 28: archive is not a ZIP archive.:
java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
        at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.positionAtEndOfCentralDirectoryRecord(ZipFile.java:871)
        at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.positionAtCentralDirectory(ZipFile.java:801)
        at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.populateFromCentralDirectory(ZipFile.java:542)
        at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:217)
        at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:193)
        at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:154)
        at com.android.repository.util.InstallerUtil.unzip(InstallerUtil.java:98)
        at com.android.repository.impl.installer.BasicInstaller.doPrepare(BasicInstaller.java:83)
        at com.android.repository.impl.installer.AbstractPackageOperation.prepare(AbstractPackageOperation.java:312)
        at com.android.builder.sdk.DefaultSdkLoader.installRemotePackages(DefaultSdkLoader.java:361)
        at com.android.builder.sdk.DefaultSdkLoader.installTarget(DefaultSdkLoader.java:239)
        at com.android.builder.sdk.DefaultSdkLoader.getTargetInfo(DefaultSdkLoader.java:161)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.initTarget(SdkHandler.java:183)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.ensureTargetSetup(BasePlugin.java:960)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:732)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$null$4(BasePlugin.java:670)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$5(BasePlugin.java:666)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1$1.run(DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator.java:155)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.reapply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:58)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1.run(DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator.java:152)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction.execute(DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator.java:149)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:80)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:324)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:234)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:187)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:184)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.stepEvaluationListener(DefaultProject.java:1418)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:193)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:110)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:687)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluationDependsOn(DefaultProject.java:767)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluationDependsOn(DefaultProject.java:759)
        at org.gradle.api.Project$evaluationDependsOn.call(Unknown Source)
        at build_4rgezgdmxun8fe0vodu752udi$_run_closure3.doCall(D:\Gowtham\AppDev\Projects\county\android\build.gradle:24)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:264)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:418)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:434)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:155)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:106)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil$WrappedConfigureAction.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:167)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator$4.execute(BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.java:108)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions.with(Actions.java:245)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator$3.run(BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.java:79)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.runProjectConfigureAction(BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.java:76)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.access$400(BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.java:30)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator$2.doRunProjectConfigure(BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator$BlockConfigureBuildOperation.run(BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.java:161)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.runBlockConfigureAction(BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.java:67)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.subprojects(BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.subprojects(DefaultProject.java:1144)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:479)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:191)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.java:30)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript$ScriptDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BasicScript.java:133)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDynamicObject.java:160)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.invokeMethod(BasicScript.java:82)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:74)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:169)
        at build_4rgezgdmxun8fe0vodu752udi.run(D:\Gowtham\AppDev\Projects\county\android\build.gradle:23)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:90)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$2.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:211)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:69)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:66)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:63)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:48)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:63)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:41)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:105)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:687)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:140)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:60)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:41)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuild.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:274)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.configureBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:182)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:141)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:77)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:74)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:154)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:96)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:74)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:79)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
"Install Android SDK Platform 28 (revision: 6)" failed.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\Gowtham\AppDev\Projects\county\android\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Failed to install the following SDK components:
         platforms;android-28 Android SDK Platform 28
     Install the missing components using the SDK manager in Android Studio.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7m 32s
  Command: D:\Gowtham\AppDev\Projects\county\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

---

Build.Gradle file in /android/app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.smartherd.county"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

---

Build.gradle file in /android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

---

Questions---

What's the problem here?
How can i resolve this?

Comment: This link may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49045393/flutter-run-no-connected-devices

Answer (score -1):

To generate apk connected device is not needed.

Below is the command i run for my sample project and it is successfully built. Used Android Studio 3.4.1 and latest flutter sdk and On Mac machine i am running.

$ flutter build apk

Initializing gradle...                                              2.3s

Resolving dependencies...                                          21.8s

Calling mockable JAR artifact transform to create file:

/Users/myname/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/android.jar/0dc309503743c11f537976eb951ae317/android.jar with input /Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-28/android.jar

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      61.0s

Built build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk (8.0MB).