# Is there any solution to get the device connected as my Emulator and run the output?Flutter run:No Devices Connected

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, android-emulator

[Click here to load the screenshot of Android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQ9Wt.jpg)

I am new to Flutter, I am not able to run the Output in Android Studio as it shows no devices connected...yet I have the emulator of Pixel 3a installed as also shown in the above screenshot, it also says that **my emulator not applicable for main. dart configuration**

Here is the output in CMD

```
flutter run:  

No connected devices.

the output of flutter doctor:

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
    [√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 
    10.0.17134.950], locale en-IN)
    [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 
    29.0.0)
    [√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    [!] VS Code (version 1.37.1)
        X Flutter extension not installed; install from
          https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter
    [!] Connected device
        ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Is there any solution to get a device connected as my Emulator and run the output?
How do I run my Output in any other way?? Preferably by the Virtual Emulator!

Comment: it's a bug on android studio 3.5

Comment: you can restart your android studio, and try

Comment: I have also tried restarting it but it seems to remain the same, I also tried installing other emulators instead of pixel 3a too

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/49045393/8822337

Comment: and this one too https://stackoverflow.com/q/16596877/8822337

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to AVD Manager(Android Vertual Device Manager) on android studio.
2. Click play button on Action Row

How to open AVD Manager[https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds]

Answer (score 0):

Most of such errors get resolved by **updating** the Android Studio. You can get the update by **choosing Help > Check for Updates** (Android Studio > Check for Updates on macOS)