# Visual code does not recognize my android phone

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I'm working on flutter and I'm using as a Visual Studio Code editor I've already created my project. the problem is that my phone which is already in debug mode is not recognized in Visual Studio Code. Help me please.

```
Version: 1.38.1 (system setup)
Commit: b37e54c98e1a74ba89e03073e5a3761284e3ffb0
Date: 2019-09-11T13:35:15.005Z
Electron: 4.2.10
Chrome: 69.0.3497.128
Node.js: 10.11.0
V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 6.2.9200
```

Comment: Have you tried checking if ADB is detecting the device? Type `adb devices` or `flutter devices` on your terminal.

Comment: Check this post [No connected devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49045393/flutter-run-no-connected-devices)

Comment: have you installed google usb drivers available in the sdk

Comment: Is it still not being detected?

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Windows on your machine, make sure that device driver is installed. Check this guide [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb). You can then try restarting adb by running `adb kill-server` on terminal, then run `adb start-server`. To verify if your device has been detected, you can run `flutter devices`.