# Device (Android) not found - Flutter from ChromeOS

Tags: flutter

I've just installed Flutter on a Chromebook, together with Android Studio and VSCode (and all the plugins). All good so far, I've created that new project to test if / how it runs but unfortunately no android phone is recognized.

Mentions:

- I've tried on 2 phones, both with Developer Options ON and USB Debugging ON. The phone is cable-connected to laptop
- I run flutter doctor and all is green, with one exception: no devices available.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flutter run: No connected devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49045393/flutter-run-no-connected-devices)