# No connected devices found; please connect a device

Tags: android, flutter

I just open my flutter project in android studio but android studio cannot detect any device. I already installed two emulator from AVD manager but still I face with this error

Comment: I believe this [No devices connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49045393/flutter-run-no-connected-devices) will help you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flutter run: No connected devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49045393/flutter-run-no-connected-devices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly this happens when your Android SDK path is not configured.
To do this you can do it as follow:

1. First of all make sure make sure you followed the installation process
2. Go to `File -> Project Structure` select `Project` from left tab and select `<No SDK>`
3. Then from the devices list click on one of the AVDs to run [image]
4. Make sure your `build gradle` correctly done
5. Run `flutter doctor` to check if devices are connected
6. Run your project

Comment: Does it show the connected devices when you run `flutter doctor` in the terminal ?

Comment: Then definitely you missed something during the installation.

Comment: So what should I do now

Comment: I suggest go through the official installation process 


 https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows

Answer (score 1):

I found that the old virtual devices created from the Kotlin projects can't be used with Flutter. You need to recreate a new one for it to appear in the toolbar drop menu like the image below

[image]