# dart code unable to run in android studio. how should I go about making sure I set it up right?

Tags: android, flutter

after installing android studio and setting up flutter and dart I've noticed that I can't seem to run anything, when I watch tutorials they always have a green arrow shaped button and some other functionalities, all of which are gray on my screen and don't really do anything. here's a picture...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0LqB.png)

I suspect it has something to do with the 'no devices' but i'm confused because I have an android phone connected to my laptop.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From a console window which has the Flutter directory in the path (see above), run the following command to see if there are any platform dependencies you need to complete the setup or not working: `C:\flutter>flutter doctor`

This command checks your environment and displays a report of the status of your Flutter installation. Check the output carefully for other software you may need to install or further tasks to perform

Comment: I tried running flutter doctor but it says I'm good to go. But I'm having the same issues

Comment: as it turns out I got the script to run by right clicking it and selecting "run script", and doing this enabled the run button to work.

Comment: Have you seen this:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49045393/flutter-run-no-connected-devices)