# Android device is not showing up on VS Code/Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, dart, usb-debugging

VS code and Android Studio is recognizing my connected android device.
My device is showing up on file explorer though. I have turned on USB debugging from settings too.

[image]

Below is the result of `flutter doctor`

```dart
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.493], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.64.2)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

**What I have tried**

https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/1634#issuecomment-485071966
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb#Win10

Answer (score 7):

After I set up Flutter and got flutter doctor running, I plugged in my Android phone. Neither flutter doctor or VS Code could detect it!

I already turned on Developer Options and USB debugging “File sharing”.

Developer Options > Select USB Configuration > Change it from “File Transfer” (default option) to Charging”
The phone will ask if you want to always allow USB debugging from this device.

Say yes.

After that, VS Code was able to detect my Android phone, and I was able to run my app on it!

Answer (score 3):

Please check you follow the proper steps to connect your Device.

1. Turn on the developer options on your device
2. Enable USB debugging on your Device
3. When connecting the device to your Machine don't select charge only mode
4. Accept Certificate in certificate popup for the machine after connecting the device

Answer (score 1):

Please check link below. It might solve your problem of not showing devices (Message "flutter run: No connected devices"):-
[Message "flutter run: No connected devices"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49045393/message-flutter-run-no-connected-devices)

Answer (score 1):

Go to your terminal and run this command.

> flutter devices

This will verify if flutter has recognized your device or not.

Also check and verify this.

> flutter config --android-sdk ANDROID_SDK_PATH

At last you can check this link - https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos#set-up-your-android-device

Answer (score 0):

Once  check the output of the command

```
adb devices
```

If the list is empty then the system has recognized your device as a storage device. Then you need to install android SDK from the Android Studio IDE and try again.

Answer (score 0):

just change the USB option to **photo transfer** it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Also if nothing helps - try to change usb cable. For me with my Mac it helps if no device shown/it disappears from time to time.