# Flutter not seeing emulator in Android studio - no device selected

Tags: android, flutter, sdk, android-emulator

I've updated my Android Studio and cannot see anymore my running emulators for running/debugging my app.

[image]

Previously I had Bumblebee (2021.1.1) and updated to Chipmunk (2021.2.1) and I encounter this issue.

I want to mention that previously everything was working fine, I've also researched on the internet and couldn't find anything that I'm missing, I have the following or tried:

- Flutter set in PATH
- Android SDK set in PATH and ANDROID_HOME env. var.
- Android SDK set in Project Settings
- Tried opening from running, Device Manager and from terminal, same behavior.
- Android Studio plugins updated
- Set up: `flutter config --android-sdk`
- My emulator is loading in cold boot, not using any snapshot
- Set-up licenses
- I'm using fvm, flutter in terminal works ok, `flutter doctor`, `flutter devices`, they work fine, just that there are no device online.

I've also tried to downgrade again, but still not working, although 1 out of 10 it worked, after quit or restart.
I will try to also change the way I use the SDK, although from terminal it works ok.

Does anybody else encounter this issue recently?
Thanks!

Comment: what do you get after running `flutter emulators`

Comment: Hi @YeasinSheikh they are no detected, same `flutter devices`

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49045393/10157127) might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some random debugging, I found out that Docker Desktop was causing the problem. After I close it, the emulator appeared...

Want to point out that the port wasn't being used:
`sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P | grep 5554`

Answer (score 1):

have you tried clicking wipe data

[image]

Comment: Yes, I also tried that, or creating new ones.