# Android Studio Emulator not showing up to run flutter app

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-emulator, flutter-run

I am trying to run my Flutter app in Android Studio. But when I try to select a device to launch, I am prompted to launch the Android Emulator, which is already running.
When running the flutter devices command, the following message is displayed:

```
• Device emulator-5554 is not authorized.
You might need to check your device for an authorization dialog.
```

I tried to find a solution ([similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49045393/message-flutter-run-no-connected-devices)) but it didn't help.

The output of `flutter doctor`:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.11, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1555], locale ru-RU)
[X] Windows Version (Unable to confirm if installed Windows version is 10 or greater)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.77.3)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
    ! Device emulator-5554 is not authorized.
      You might need to check your device for an authorization dialog.
[√] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

`JAVA_HOME` value:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr
```

USB debugging is enabled ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmBFN.png)), but nothing happens when running `flutter devices` or `flutter doctor`. Trying to revoke permissions and execute commands again does not help either.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to create a new emulator? Make sure that the emulator is google play compatible.

You can also try to run the command `adb devices` and see if the emulator shows up.

IF the new emulator dosent work try to turn it of and run the command

`adb kill-server`
and then
`adb start-server`

And start the emulator agian and see if it works then.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, I tried creating a new emulator. And it is compatible with Google Play.
Running `adb devices` displays the following: `emulator-5554 unauthorized`.
Doing `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server` did not help.

Comment: Ok,  Try to revoke USB debugging and start it again. And see if you get a popup on you phone asking to allow USB debugging

Answer (score 0):

So, I got a problem with the **Pixels 2** and **2 XL API 28 (Pie)** and here's what to do :

- Set and run the device normally
- Turn on the developer features: go to the settings, then '**System**', '**About Emulated Device**', tap 5 times on '**Build Number**'
- Go back, reveal the advanced options, then go to '**Developer Options**'
- Make sure '**USB debugging**' is on
- Find '**default USB configuration**'
- Click on it, it will open a menu, then select '**File Transfer**' instead of '**No data transfer**'
- I think it's good but you can also click inside your notifications on '**Virtual SD card**' and set it for transferring photos and media, in order to be sure
- Open your PowerShell (or cmd, or what you want) with the emulator still opened and check if it's getting recognized with '**flutter doctor**' or '**flutter devices**'
- Go to your project folder with '**cd [your folder's path]**'
- Type '**flutter run**' to launch your app in the emulator

It should work! It did for me, I think the problem comes from the USB default configuration. I hope it helped, have a nice programming session!