# Flutter doctor error -cmdline tools component missing and Android sdkmanager tool not found. Windows

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to setup an android emulator but I don't have intel. I've been through so many similar pages but none have given me an answer on why I can't get my flutter doctor to work. Here is my flutter doctor results:

```
C:\Users\icetr>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1645], locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    X cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.1.4)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.66.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

C:\Users\icetr>flutter doctor --android-licenses
Android sdkmanager not found. Update to the latest Android SDK and ensure that the cmdline-tools are installed to
resolve this.
```

Here is my android sdk folder:
[image]

And my cmdline tools folder:

[image]

Inside the lastest folder:

[image]

Inside the bin folder:

[image]

Here's my paths:

[image]

Here's my Android Studio SDK Tools tab:

[image]

If anyone needs anymore information just ask.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android SDK is missing command line tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50220036/android-sdk-is-missing-command-line-tools)

Comment: No I tried all the solutions provided to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After ALOT of trial an error, I had to finally delete all my android packages, Uninstaller Android Studio, and reinstall. Then I deleted all my paths, and reput them in and it fixed it all.

Answer (score 0):

Install NDK Manager and android command-line tool from android Studio. Also, accept the android licenses.

`flutter doctor --android-licenses`

Comment: I appreciate the comments but I clearly left pictures of both of those folders (which trust me I've re-download as well).

Comment: Had same issue and this worked for me. Had to find the detailed steps on youtibe (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZxanQ4IOt_Q&ab_channel=TechNowTv) but tis basically what @monzim said.