# Vscode showing erros after locating flutter and dart sdk

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, dart

I located the flutter and dart sdk paths in the `settings.json` file but still Vscode showing errors.

I think it's related to the sdk path only.

**Edit: It's not detecting any devices**

[image]

[image]

Comment: try pub get from comand in vs code

Comment: Thanks bro, it worked. But now when I write `flutter doctor` command, it shows "Unable to locate Android SDK". What to do now?

Comment: Did you correctly setup Flutter? Did you add Android_Home into your Environment Variable?

Comment: Yes I did the setup correctly, but what is Android_Home? Where can I find it?

Comment: Actually I used the custom download location for Android Sdk. What can I do now?

Comment: @HardikKumar see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44485848/android-sdk-cannot-be-found-by-flutter

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4iZW9-D_JhU

Comment: Thank you again @ParthPitroda You helped me a lot.