# Android Sdk and Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I installed flutter and android studio together with the SDK.
Android studio is working well but on running flutter doctor,  I get an error;
' Unable to locate Android Sdk'

Thanks in advance for helping me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android SDK cannot be found by flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44485848/android-sdk-cannot-be-found-by-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

**installing the platform-tools resolves the problem**. For this, **open Android Studio**, click on **SDK Manager** in the toolbar or click Tools > **SDK Manager**, click on **SDK Tools**, then check-mark ‘✓’ Android-SDK Platform-Tools (as shown below).

[image]