# SDK error in React native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

i am new to react native and an trying to run the project on emmulator "react-native run-android" . iam getting the error.

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> The SDK directory 'D:\ReactNativeLearning\zupportdeskchat\ZDReactNative\zupportdeskapp\android\"D:\Android\sdk"' does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.253 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

My Sdk Folder is in

```
sdk.dir ="D:/Android/sdk"
```

I set it up in local.properties.

Can someone help me to fix this tnx.

Comment: are you running it on windows? try: *sdk.dir = D\:\\Android\\sdk*
this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634352/react-native-android-build-failed-sdk-location-not-found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working on windows system then path should be:

```
sdk.dir=D\:\\Projects\\Android\\sdk
```

Clear build cache and npm cache then try to make build.

Also check, your device is connected or not.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you haven't connected a device or opened the emulator. So first connect the device to the machine and try `react-native run-android` or run the emulator and enter `react-native run-android`