# How to fix the "SDK directory does not exist"?

Tags: sdk

So I'm trying to get my react native software to run and it's popping up with an error saying The SDK directory 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android studio; ' does not exist. How can I fix this?

Comment: Install Android studio. To do react native setup with Android studio you can refer: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native android build failed. SDK location not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634352/react-native-android-build-failed-sdk-location-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

Lookup 2 places:

- [Possible duplicate of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634352/react-native-android-build-failed-sdk-location-not-found?rq=1)
- [React Native start Guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started)

If you installed all necessary things listed in guide just do:
`react-native init YOURPROJECTNAME`

and after build add `local.properties` file in android folder of your app.
It should contain line: `sdk.dir = C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk`