# Android SDK not found - React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, android-studio, react-native, sdk

I am trying to setup React Native for the first time, but I can't get ahead of the **"SDK location not found"** problem. I installed the SDK into the standard path in AppData and also tried to create a `local.properties` file in the project folder ([React Native android build failed. SDK location not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634352/react-native-android-build-failed-sdk-location-not-found))

I'm out of ideas what the problem could be. I really need help and I'm glad for every answer.

Thank you!

Comment: are you using windows or other OS?

Comment: I'm using Windows

Comment: try set up the ANDROID_HOME to enviornment path like c:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Comment: if again facing issue then set up path to system env. like C:\Android\tools;C:\Android\platform-tools