# Could not install the app on the device (react)

Tags: react-native, react-android

I trying to run the `react-native run-android` through my React Project. After that, 
[I got this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fmsc0.png)

Comment: It is ok that you attach an image of the problem. However, it would be recommended to write a brief description of the problem and which method to fix the problem you tried.

Answer (score 1):

If you are installed sdk correctly, you can create an empty file in your android project named "local.properties" (if it does not exist) and define sdk address in it like this:

```
sdk.dir=/home/USERNAME/Android/Sdk
```

This address may changes based on your settings, it's the default address in linux.
I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using windows.
Add an environment variable ANDROID_HOME that points to

```
C:\Users\<your-user-name>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634352/react-native-android-build-failed-sdk-location-not-found

Answer (score 0):

You must follow the steps described in the URL:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

go to Building Project with native Code and follow the steps and you must have a virtual or real device for testing. To check if any device is connected or not just go to your terminal and type `adb devices` and if there is any device it will show.