# How to debug "Build failed with an exception / SDK location not found" in Android?

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-studio, react-native

I'm new in React-Native. I tried several solution in some forums but didn't help. Bellow the errors .

```
   Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.407]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\xampp\htdocs\Hands-on React-Native\TripPlane>react-native run-android
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634352/react-native-android-build-failed-sdk-location-not-found

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup ReactNative properly.

*I have consider that android studio is already installed and emulator or android device is already attached*

**Follow below steps!**

**1]** Install JDK from [official site](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

**2]** Install NodeJs from [official site](https://nodejs.org/en/)

**3]** Install Python 2 form [official site](https://www.python.org/downloads/)

**4]** Install ReactNative CLI , open CMD [ right click and run as administrator ]

- Type `C:\WINDOWS\system32>node -v`  // to get node version
- Type `C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm install -g react-native-cli`    // to install RN CLI

**5]** Create workspace of your RN projects
- `D:\ReactNative>react-native init projectname`  //it will generate project inside mentioned path.

**6]** setup environment variable

- set up new variable under user variable (if not exist) `JAVA_HOME` with the value 
  `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2` (your JDK path)
- set up new variable under user variable (if not exist) `Path` with the value 
  `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools`  //your sdk platform tools path

**7]** run your project using following command inside CMD
`D:\ReactNative>react-native run android`

Comment: Sorry! But the step 6 I don't understand. I cannot find the User variable to add this path that you wrote. In witch file should I find or create a new file ?

Comment: inside search box of windows start up menu search `environment variable`. click on `environment variable` button. then one popup will come with 2 options.user variable and system variable. you need to edit inside user variable.

Comment: Radhey thanks for your support. But I did all the step that you mentioned up and did not help. Take look the error bellow

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '11.0.1'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html