# React-Native trying to run android, getting an error about /bin/sh: /usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb: No such file or directory

Tags: android, react-native

I have updated my $PATH to include the correct location of my adb sdk, but react-native is insisting on using /usr/local/share/android-sdk, instead of /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools. Is there another way to change this? It will not run my android emulator because of this error.

Here is my path:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk:Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
```

bash profile

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK=/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
```

Comment: can u share your .bash_profile?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634352/react-native-android-build-failed-sdk-location-not-found

Comment: I looked in the local.properties, and the sdk.dir is correct.

Comment: try this in bash_profile

export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, the bash_profile ANDROID_HOME wasn't being recognized, or something. I had to run this in the terminal

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk
```

to get it to work. Finally did, thanks for your answers!

Comment: Awesome, this helped me. I added the line you cited on my Mac's ~/.zshrc file which persists it for future sessions.