# Android SDK is not recognized in React Native App

Tags: android, react-native, sdk

I am trying to get android studio set up for a mobile and web app that I am creating with react native. When I attempt to run react-native run-android, the emulator opens but the app fails to install.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwLXy.png)

I then run react-native doctor. The results are as follows:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/74mrZ.png)

The android sdk is showing up as N/A. These are my environment variables:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/oq6Qi.png)

I have installed what I believe to be everything I need in Android Studio. I have the version of the SDK, but when I attempt to install the android sdk command line tools it finished and shows up as not installed.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/sniTN.png)

I have tried to use the react-native doctor to fix these issues but it does not solve the issue. I have tried to install the command line tools multiple times through android studio but no matter what I do it shows up as not installed afterwards.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of terminal output. Just copy and paste the test into your question and format it as code.

Comment: BTW there what s not Android SDK Version 33, most likely the command is not searching for Android SDK but for the build-tools package version 33, which you can install using Android SDK.

Comment: @Robert Sorry about the screenshots. Isn't the build tools what I am downloading in the 4th screenshot?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android SDK not found for react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62635201/android-sdk-not-found-for-react-native)

Comment: That was the page that I was using to try to fix it. I installed the build tools fine, but the command line tools say not installed after installing them and I was thinking that is the issue but I do not know how to fix it.