# React Native Android

Tags: android, react-native

I already installed Android Studio and all the required tools and SDK version based on the documentation of react-native, I also followed all the instructions on the documentation. however , I dont understand this error, I'm new to react-native.

[image]

info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
/bin/sh: adb: command not found
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:installDebug'.

> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/Users/rochesterpeduche/Desktop/AwesomeTSProject/android/local.properties'.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

Comment: As the error says, it did not find Android SDK. Please refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634352/react-native-android-build-failed-sdk-location-not-found which should solve your problem.

Comment: You should also upvote the answer if you found it to be helpful so that it can help others as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set environment variable for android sdk like this :

Go to File explorer and right click

[image]

Then go to properties and select Advance system settings

[image]

Then select Environment Variables

[image]

Then select User Variables and path variable inside that

[image]

Then add path to your android SDK as shown in above image and click save and check!!!!