# How to open the AVD manager on OSX from iTerm2?

Tags: macos, android-studio, sdk, android-virtual-device

I am using Homebrew to install Android dev tools

```
brew install gradle
brew install android-sdk
```

Then I am getting command not found when running `avdmanager`.

```
➜  ~ avdmanager
zsh: command not found: avdmanager
```

How to open the AVD manager on OSX from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables missing maybe?

Considering the **SDK** is installed under `/Users/<your_user>/Library/Android/sdk` folder which is the Android Studio preferred SDK location, but it works fine under `/usr/local/share/android-sdk` as well, which is a location pretty much used on CI mostly.

Add the following either on the `.zshrc` file. ( or `.bash_profile` on iTerm )

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

On the terminal

```
➜  ~ source .zshrc
```

It outputs

```
➜  ~ sdkmanager --version
26.1.1
```

See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables