# React native android emulator: could not create task ':realm:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: react-native, android-emulator, realm

I have macbook M1 and trying to run Android emulator. When I run a command to launch the emulator I get the errorsCould not create task ':realm:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not create task ':realm:forwardDebugPort'.
> > SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/Users/.../btp-react-native-field-data-capture/android/local.properties'.

I don't have this file and what do I need to add there?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, but was able to resolve by creating a new file named "local.properties" in my android folder.

You just need to add the following line.

sdk.dir = /Users/YOUR_MAC_USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk

Reference below.

[React Native android build failed. SDK location not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634352/react-native-android-build-failed-sdk-location-not-found)