# react-native does not find Android SDK 33, but it was installed

Tags: react-native

My build for android failed. So I ran ( **npx react-native doctor** ) but it doesn't recognize p ( **SDK 33** ) that I already installed, has anyone had this problem?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native android build failed. SDK location not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634352/react-native-android-build-failed-sdk-location-not-found)