# Android SDK is not getting detected by react-native

Tags: react-native, android-studio

Since the last three days, I have been trying to set up a development environment for react native but it is always showing this error.
[sdk version : n/a whenever I run npx react-native doctor command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oSlm.png)

I have installed all other tools(build-tools,platform-tools, cmdline-tools etc.) along with sdk 33 and sdk 34 and also set the environment variables path.

System config. : Windows 11, 64-bit

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634352/react-native-android-build-failed-sdk-location-not-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634352/react-native-android-build-failed-sdk-location-not-found) might be helpful